# Add line breaks to a JavaScript pop-out box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add line breaks to this message box so that it will display each of the different items on a separate line? At the moment it just displays them right after each other and it does not look great.

```
var addresses = $.map(oTable.rows('.selected').data(), function (items) {
    return items[2]
});

if (leng) {      
    var r = confirm('You have selected '+leng+' records');
    if (r == true) {
        var s = confirm('Email address you selected are : ' + addresses);
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to see what happens, what you want and where your full code is. Please, read that and edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: sorry i,m new to all of this but Yeldar Kurmangalyev seemed to understand me and provided me with the answer i needed 

thank you and ill try to provide a little bit more information next time i need help :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the misunderstanding. However, the link I shared with you is mandatory and this too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask That links are for obtain better and faster answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `\n` to make a new line in your `alert` or `prompt`.

Assuming that `addresses` is an array of strings, you can use `Array.prototype.join` to output them one in a line:

```
var s = confirm('Email address you selected are: \n' + addresses.join('\n'));
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/ue0gLf59/).